# while executing this programe i getting same output every time as file not found even if file is available in my pc

Tags: linux

give me this error:

**" file not found "**

Here are the full code

> https://github.com/vats147/public/blob/main/l25.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

usage(){
     echo " you need to provide an argument "
     echo " usage : $0 file_ name "
}

is_file_exist(){
    local file="$1"
    [[ -f " $file " ]] && return 0 || return 1
} 
[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && usage
if(is_file_exist "$1")
then
    echo " file found "
else
    echo " file not found "
fi
```

while the executing of a programe i get same output as file not found even if file are avaliable in directory.

why?

Comment: Please post the code as part of the question, and not as a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `if` condition is invalid. It should be more like this

```
if [[ is_file_exist "$1" -eq 1 ]];then
    echo "file found"
else
    echo "file not found"
fi
```

Comment: Please be aware that in bash syntax the `if` condition doesn't use `(` instead it uses `[`